# split dataframe in batches pyspark

Tags: pyspark

My requirement is to split the dataframe in group of 2 batches with each batch containing only 2 items and batch size(BATCH in output) increasing incrementally.

```
col#1 col#2 DATE
A     1     202010
B     1.1   202010
C     1.2   202010 
D     1.3   202001
E     1.4   202001
```

O/P

```
col#1 col#2 DATE    BATCH
A     1     202010  1
B     1.1   202010  1
C     1.2   202010  2
D     1.3   202001  2
E     1.4   202001  3
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this by following approach:

```
def dfZipWithIndex (df, offset=1, colName='rowId'):   
   new_schema = StructType([StructField(colName,LongType(),True)]+ 
   df.schema.fields)   
   zipped_rdd = df.rdd.zipWithIndex()   
   new_rdd =zipped_rdd.map(lambda args: ([args[1] + offset] + list(args[0])))   
   return spark.createDataFrame(new_rdd, new_schema)

chunk_size=2 
final_new=dfZipWithIndex(input_df) 


temp_final=input_df.withColumn('BATCH',F.floor(F.col('rowId')/chunk_size)+1)
```